# A variation of the menage problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A combinatorics problem I am chewing on without success is:

3 couples and 40 others are to be arranged randomly in a row.

What is the probability that no two couples sit together ?

I have looked at the ménage approach, and derangements, but they don't fit exactly, and I am not able to think of some other "non-brute force" approach.

*Edit:*

I forgot to mention that seats are alternately marked "ladies" and "gents", but the 40 intruders can sit anywhere.

Comment: There being only a modest number of bad cases (the couples sitting together), I wonder if inclusion-exclusion could be made to work. It looks like it could be messy when couples are sitting near the ends of the row, however.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to come back to the question after a long time, I think I should post an answer using Austin Mohr's suggestion, for anyone who chances on it.

There are a total 3 couples and 40 "others", 46 seats in all

The "others" won't affect the probability, we can seat them after seating the 3 couples.

Apply inclusion-exclusion by

**(a)** Choosing couples sitting together and permuting them in 23 "couple seats"

**(b)** Permuting  ladies and gents separately in the remaining seats for their gender

1 - [C(3,1)*P(23,1)*P(22,2)^2 - C(3,2)*P(23,2)*P(21,1)^2 + C(3,3)*P(23,3)]/P(23,3)^2